# making a iphone app .xib file fit the iphone 5 4-inch screen

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

How do I make the UIImageView fit the Retina 4-inch display? Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are developing your app for iOS 6 then use **Autolayouts** for this.
Else you can use **AutoResizing** feature if managing height through NIB.

If you want to manage it programmatically you can use this code :

```
#define IS_IPHONE ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
#define IS_HEIGHT_GTE_568 [[UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds].size.height >= 568.0f
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( IS_IPHONE && IS_HEIGHT_GTE_568 )
```

then set frame as :

```
[your_imageview setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, IS_IPHONE_5?568.0f:480.0f)];
```

Hope it helps you.